# How to change Postscript point numbers directly or via source

Tags: fontforge

I'm trying and failing to interpolate a certain letter. I've tried copying and pasting individual paths in the glyph in the same order, selecting one path and removing overlap to reset the numbering, but no matter what I do, the letter produces jumbled results when interpolated. I'm suspecting that this has something to do with PostScript point numbers. How may I reset or change the PostScript point numbers so that the letter may interpolate correctly?

Comment: I have to say its not clear to me what you are asking about here. What do you mean by 'interpolate a letter' ? If you are trying to modify a font then you;re going to have to be **much** more explicit, PostScript supports a number of different font types. I have no clue whjat you mean by 'reset the numbering', since fonts don't have any numbering. What do you mean by 'PostScript point numbers' ? Are you asking about real number representation ? A good way forward might be to post an example PostScript program that you are trying to modify, and a description of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @KenS probably means point drawing order.

Comment: This is about FontForge, by the way.